# Why am I being told "this method could be const"?

Tags: c++

In a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething(int x) const;

private:
    int m_bar;
};
```

one is not allowed to write

```
void Foo::DoSomething(int x) const
{
    m_bar = x; // Error
}
```

I have to remove the `const` modifier, However, if I have

```
struct Data
{
    bar;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething(int x) const;
private:
    Data * m_data;
};

void Foo::DoSomething(int x) const
{
    m_data->bar = x;
}
```

then that's not only fine,but I get warned "method can be const" by code validation tools if I remove the modifier?

I shouldn't be able to modify the state of an object in a const method, irrespective of how that state is represented!

Comment: This seems to imply that m_data should also be a const pointer.  The const in your function only promises that the m_data* should not be changed (which it isn't).
Or maybe Data should not be a pointer but a small wrapper object too with a non-constant setter.

Comment: Because you aren't chaning any of your own members. You're changing a member of another class, or struct, which maybe you should be doing via its API, which might raise const-ness issues of its own for that class/struct; but not for this one.

Comment: The pointer value itself is not changed. The object pointed to is. This can lead to surprising effects sometimes. It can be worked around by using class templates like [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) or ConstPropagatingPtr from Loki. But yes, C++ lacks "pure" and usage of const can be debatable at times. If the const should be used as pure is mostly matter of convention. Personally, I use const propagation for all sorts of owning pointers. Otherwise, I tend to make the member const even when delegating to mutable ones, but that’s only my taste

Comment: "I get warned" -- sounds like you have bad code validation tools.  The method should *not* be const if it logically modifies the object, even if it does not actually modify any fields directly.

Comment: *'I shouldn't be able to modify the state of an object in a const method, irrespective of how that state is represented!'* That would require the compiler to understand your code and it's design, which is something not even ChatGPT is capable of. Sometimes this is described as the different between *logical const* (what you are talking about) and *physical const* (what the rules of C++ actually require).

Comment: It looks like the code validation tool is giving you a wrong suggestion in this case. It happens. Tools usually use heuristics to point out some code changes that are likely to  improve the code, but they can be wrong. Here you should _not_ mark the method as `const` if the method changes the observable state of the object.

Comment: @chi There is nothing wrong with it. It can be `const`. It doesn't modify the current object.

Comment: @chi the fact that I have a pointer to data, and not the data itself, is an encapsulated implementation detail. The const contract implies state will not change, but it can. If it pointed to a class with a non-const method and I tried to call that from a const context I would get an error. So why not here?

Comment: @jg_at_vividq A const pointer is not the same thing as a pointer-to-const. In your case, I agree, having a pointer is only an implementation detail, and `*p` should not be modified. C++ does not enforce that. This is because in other cases, having a pointer is not an implementation detail, but it's part of the intended behavior. If we make an "iterator"-like object (over, say, some vector of ints), then the state of the object does not include the vector. Ditto for `shared_ptr`: a `const shared_ptr<int> p{...};` allows `*p = 42;` (but not `p = ...`) since the `int` is not part of the state.

Answer (score 7):

The `const` qualifier tells the compiler that the function will not modify any member variables of the object. So if you have a pointer member variable, a `const` function will not be able to change the pointer itself.

***But*** that only goes for the actual member variable. The data that the pointer is actually pointing to is not constant. For that you need a pointer to a constant object (e.g. `Data const* m_data;`).

Comment: In C++, it's called "data member". "member variable" doesn't appear anywhere in the C++ standard.

Comment: You could mention some method to propagate that constness. Using them is a matter of style, but nonetheless they are a valuable tool.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers point somewhere. If you modify a pointer you modify where it points to.

Because pointers point somewhere you can dereference them to access the pointee. Modifying the pointee does not modify the pointer.

---

For the sake of illustration, imagine you had no pointer but instead an index into an array:

```
struct Data
{
    int x;
};

Data my_memory[42];

class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething(int x) const;
private:
    size_t m_index;  // "points to" a Data element in my_memory
};

void Foo::DoSomething(int x) const
{
    my_memory[m_index].x = x;
}
```

Of course pointers are not indices into arrays. Though as mental image it is more accurate than you might expect. The index refers to the actual object which is stored elsewhere. You can modify the index which has no effect on the object. You can use the index to access the object and modify it without modifying the index. Thats just the same as your pointer does.

---

I hope now it is obvious that `Foo::DoSomething` should be `const`. You are modifiying the `Data` object, which is not part of `Foo`. `Foo` only contains a pointer to the object. `DoSomething` does not modify that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The object is taking some X memory at some address P.
A member function of with the `const` qualifier, can't change **DIRECTLY** the memory X at at this address, this is why a function can be mark as `const`

In the case below, we **CAN** change the memory of the object inside a `const` object

```
struct A {
    public:
    A(): x(5) { x_p =&x;};
    void update_x()  const { *x_p = 3;}
    
     int x;
     int *x_p;

};
```

Compile and run :

```
int main()
{   
    A a;
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
    a.update_x();
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}
```

would get:

```
3
5
```

Comment: Not that I want to de-zombify this thread, but... apparently
```void Foo::Nuke() const { delete this; }```
is fine and I'm sorry, I don't think this is a very robust concept :D